# Just installed Astra-linux (Debian?) and trying to get wifi to work

Tags: debian, wifi

I just installed Astra-linux ( http://www.astralinux.com/debian.html and http://www.astralinux.com/download-ce.html ) on my MBPr (in /dev/sda8) and the wired connection works but not the wireless. I'm coming from being a mint user so am unfamiliar with Debian based OSs. In fact, I would also **like to know if** Astra-Linux Common is basically just (for my purposes of installing, maintaining, using as a regular user, etc.) a Debian OS.

But regarding the wifi... I earlier installed it and got a request for this information;

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

x@x-MacBookPro ~ $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
  03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0134]
  Kernel driver in use: wl
  Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

But I had to reinstall for other reasons. Anyway, now when I type the same commands I get;

```
x@x:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
  03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0134]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
--
  0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 GigabitEthernet PCIe [14e4:1682]
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:00f6]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

I was following along on some sites that suggested looking at b43, b43legacy, etc. ( https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx ) but I do not find them in the synaptic search or apt-cache search.

So here is my sources.d list;

```
#deb cdrom:[OS Astra Linux 1.11 orel - amd64 DVD ]/ orel contrib main non-free
#deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/current/repository orel main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/current/orel/repository orel main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/frozen/orel/latest/repository orel main contrib non-free
```

But I don't know if I should add "debian" versions to this list... or something else to find the wifi, and probably other things as this is a fresh install.

By the way, I've had success (easily) with Linux Mint 17.1,2,3 and 18.1 as far as wireless just working right out of the box.

Thanks!

**PS** 
In case helpful:

```
x@x:~$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID="AstraLinuxCE"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Astra Linux CE 1.11 (Orel)"
DISTRIB_RELEASE=1.11
DISTRIB_CODENAME=orel
PRETTY_NAME="Astra Linux (Orel 1.11)"
NAME="Astra Linux (Orel)"
ID=astra
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.astra-linux.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.astra-linux.com/support"
VARIANT_ID=orel
VARIANT=Orel
VERSION_ID=1.11
sbh@sbh:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.2.0-23-pax (builder@build) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) ) #28astra39 SMP Thu Apr 7 07:47:04 MSK 2016
x@x:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: AstraLinuxCE
Description:    Astra Linux CE 1.11 (Orel)
Release:        1.11
Codename:       orel
```

Also, I can access my working Linux Mint 18.1 partition (/dev/sda6) if need be...

And I just found this: (as I recall seeing "wl") before on my linux mint... **If** there is no repository, can I just install it with dpkg?

https://wiki.debian.org/wl

**SOLVED**

So with the help of @GAD3R and @arochester, as well as the link: http://www.oldnix.org/wifi-linux-iw/ I was able to get the wifi up and running, as well as learn a little about Debian and this particular distro. (It seems that there are several equivalent packages in this distro, e.g. instead of iwconfig, there is /sbin/iw)

The comment may have helped, which was the first thing I did, at which point modprobe gave the error complaining of no source for the kernel. So I installed: linux-pax, linux-headers-pax, linux-headers-4.2.0-23* linux-tools, iw, wicd-gtk (last was just nicer than existing). I also judiciously approved install of recommended packages.

Without a reboot I don't know when it started working, but at the end of the 3 or 4 instructions in the linked page, it was all working.

*If anyone wants some more info about this system I'll try to provide as much as I can.*

Comment: Install the `dkms` package through `apt` command then download the `.deb` file `broadcom-sta-dkms` from [backports](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie-backports/broadcom-sta-dkms) and install it and run `modprobe wl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astra Linux is a Debian derivative. It is a Debian "type" distro, but it is not just Debian. Things might have been added, taken way or changed, so it becomes (similar, but) something else. So people who use pure Debian cannot be expected to answer all questions about "look-alikes"

There are about 130 distros "based" on Debian. About 2/3 of all Linux distros are Debian "based".

To get your wifi working you might look at https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookAir/6-2

It says:

**WiFi**

The Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter works with driver 'wl' in the dkms source for the Broadcom STA (binary-only) device driver.

Install the package broadcom-sta-dkms and load the driver 'wl'. (Tested with Jessie and Sid). "

Depending on your exact model of your wifi card you have to use a specific driver. My wifi card model

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
>   [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

With the id of your wifi card (in my case: 14e4:43a0) go to this page and find all details about how to get your card working: http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/